# Maximum mapping distance rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using a Kinect.
Is there a way to set the max mapping distance to like 3.5 Meters to prevent noise from being in the image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251875/maximum-mapping-distance-rtabmap/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2017-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In rtabmapviz, this parameter is under Preferences->3D Rendering. In RVIZ, the [rtabmap_ros/MapCloud](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Map_Cloud_Display) plugin has also this parameter. For the output `/rtabmap/cloud_map`, the ros parameter (default 4 meters) is `cloud_max_depth` (for rtabmap < 0.11.11) or `Grid/DepthMax` (for rtabmap >= 0.11.11).

**EDIT**

To limit the distance of the extracted visual features used for visual odometry or loop closure detection, the parameter is `Vis/MaxDepth`. You can set it in `rtabmap_args:="--Vis/MaxDepth 3.5"` or in launch file:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
   ...
   <param name="Vis/MaxDepth" type="string" value="3.5"/> <!-- loop closure detection -->
</node>
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry">
   ...
   <param name="Vis/MaxDepth" type="string" value="3.5"/> <!-- odometry -->
</node>
```

Note that parameter `Vis/EstimationType` set to `1` (PnP transform estimation) is more robust to far noisy features.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-16**:
I am using rtabmap 0.11.8 but whenever I use my launch file with the adjusted parameters it will continue mapping to far away. Also tried changing the Vis/Maxdepth without any result.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-01-16**:
Can you tell which topic is the problem?

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-16**:
Hi, I think the depthimage, the problem is because it is taking points from a large distance much noise comes into the image + the ceiling. Is there a way to only take points which are closer then like 2 meters or something?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-01-16**:
Updated answer.

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-17**:
Hi matlabbe I think I am a big to vague, I want to only map points which are closer then 3.5 meters. So still take features from the points far away but only put the points in the map when they are closer then 3.5 meter from the Kinect.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-01-23**:
Can you add an image of which points you are referring. For the point cloud in rtabmapviz, in Preferences->3D Rendering there is a Max Depth parameters that can be set for example so the 3D point cloud map includes only points under this range from the kinect.